# How to hide custom fields on the registration form?

Tags: users, 8

I have added a lot of fields in the user profile, and sorted them using Gield Groups module tabs. Аnd now when registering the user, on the register form appears all fields and field groups tabs.

How can I hide all custom field and tabs on registration form and leave only email and one of custom field? Or can I create custom registration module with custom module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the registration form in "Manage form display" of the "Account settings":

**/admin/config/people/accounts/form-display**

Go to the bottom of this page and in "Custom Display Settings" enable the use of custom display settings for the "Register" form.

Then you get a tab "Register" at the top of the page. Here you can configure which fields are displayed.

Comment: Thanx work as i need!