# Render custom field from user registration form

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to render a custom field that shows up on the user registration form on a separate new form that creates users of a particular role with specific permissions.

I have everything working except being able to render this custom field.

When I view the field under the user registration form settings page, it says it's an entity reference field. When it renders it has 4 check boxes.

I've figured out how to kint out the fields that are on the user registration form from my new form, but I can't figure out how to render the specific one that I need.

```
$entityTypeManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
$fields = $entityTypeManager->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user');

foreach ($fields as $field_name) {
  kint($field_name);
}
```

That gives me a listing of all of the fields in the user registration.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Normally you would create a custom form mode and configure the field widgets you need. I think you are asking the question because you built the form from scratch. This is easy for simple field types, but a lot of work for complex ones.

Comment: Yeah it's a from scratch build within a module. This has to be rolled out and turned on in production, which we have minimal control over because of a federal client. I'm finding very little on creating custom registration forms and reusing fields from user forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form mode is configuration which you can roll out via CMI (drush cex/cim) or install with the module by including the YAML files in the modules config folder.

Implementing a new register form mode is not very intuitive. The basics:

1. Create the form mode:

   ```
   /admin/structure/display-modes/form
   ```
2. Enable and configure it like in this questions for the pre-installed *Register* form mode:

   [How to hide custom fields on the registration form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213011/how-to-hide-custom-fields-on-the-registration-form)
3. To place the new form mode on a page you need either a contrib module

   https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_manager

   or custom code:

   [How do I load a form with a specific form display (form mode)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230527/how-do-i-load-a-form-with-a-specific-form-display-form-mode)

   or a custom route:

   *mymodule.routing.yml*

   ```
   mymodule.register2:
     path: '/admin/people/ch-create'
     defaults:
       _entity_form: 'user.register2'
       _title: 'Create new account'
     requirements:
       _permission: 'register certain users'
   ```

   `register2` needs to be registered as form handler in the entity type:

   *mymodule.module*

   ```
   function mymodule_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
     $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('register2', 'Drupal\user\RegisterForm');
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok so if I understand you correctly, the user registration form has a form mode that is not accessible without jumping through some hoops (ie using this contrib module). Is that correct? I'd much rather code this instead of leaning on a contrib module, but let me look into this a little bit first. Contrib modules have to be approved and signed off on (just the natural of some fed clients).

Comment: The pre-installed *Register* form mode is the only form mode which works out of the box without additional code. For a custom form mode, like *Register 2*, you need **either** a contrib module **or** custom code.

Comment: So I'm still circling around this. I'm not really trying to create a new form mode. I'm fine with using the out of the box register form mode. I'm just trying to get an entity reference field that was added on to the user registration form into a second user registration form that creates a user with a unique role. I can access all kinds of information about the field via kint, but I can't get it to render from the buildForm function. Everything else renders fine. I guess I don't understand how a form mode is needed here if I can access the field data.

Comment: FYI....the contrib module has some errors and isn't working in Drupal 9 right now it looks like.

Comment: These two solutions are only examples to make clear what needs to be done, there are a wide range of other solutions for step 3 like building a custom form route. If you are stuck at this point ask a question with details where you want to place the second form on your site.

Comment: Oh I see. Actually....I did leave that detail out. This is an admin form. In other words, not accessible by anonymous users. The use case is that they want to let someone add users of a certain role, but don't want to give them access to the full registration form. I've that form completely built and works except I need one field from the main registration form that is an entity reference field. The path to the form is /admin/people/ch-create and everything is generated by the module I wrote. I'm just stuck at getting this one field. I haven't found much on programmatically reusing fields.

Comment: OK, then create an entity form route for the path. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me. I didn't really achieve what I wanted to. I was never able to figure out how to load one single field from the main registration form into a new registration form on the admin side. Again there is very little documentation about programmatically reusing fields. But this did help me to completely recreate the main registration form and I just altered it to my needs and assigned roles to it upon completion. Thank you for your help!